# EntityFramework: How to NOT update related objects?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

For example I have the relationship Customer - Orders (1 - N).

So every Order entity has navigation property Customer. If I just save Order into DB this object will be updated in DB too. What should I do to prevent updating of Customer in DB if I update Order?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Entity Framework will update all modified entities that are part of a particular context. This means that every entity that has been added, updated, or deleted will be committed as part of a single transaction when you call `SaveChanges();`. There's no way to save only a subset of these entities.

If you're finding that an entity is being saved when you believe it should not, then you are likely performing some kind of modification (probably an unintended update by setting the value of a property). Double-check your code to ensure that you aren't adding, modifying, or deleting a `Customer`, as it's happening somewhere.

If you don't believe this to be the case, post your code and we can take a look to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, the GUI prevents from modifying of Customer but I would like to know if it's possible to prevent on the EF layer for example if data are changed accidentally. Maybe I can change the state to Unmodified?

Comment: @Seacat: That's not the road you want to go down. You need to determine *what* is changing the values and modify the code so that it doesn't. You can set breakpoints in the setters for your `Customer` class's properties to see where the change is coming from.

Comment: The problem the GUI form has a lot of fields bound to the Entity Customer. I can handle clicking on every control but there are too many controls (text fields, checkboxes, combos etc) that I'm afraid I can miss something.

Comment: @Seacat: The controls will not set the value on the bound object unless their value is changed. If you truly want them to be read-only, either make them read-only using the appropriate property, or change the binding to be one-way (change the `DataSourceUpdateMode` to `Never`)

Comment: I've found the solution! I just call CancelEdit() on the related object before updating of the order.

Comment: @Seacat, listen to good advice.  You **don't** want to do CancelEdit.  Your Customer object is changed by code that shouldn't be touching it -- that is a potential bug.  Don't ignore it by not updating the object.  Fix the bug instead.  If your UI is allowing the user to change fields that they shouldn't be touching, then lock those UI fields to prevent the changes, not ignoring them.